# Derby.js: split client-side only code into several files

Tags: node.js, express, derbyjs

I'm trying to split some client-side-only code into several files in a Derby.js project. It has to be client-side only since it's interacting with the TinyMCE editor. So I tried:

```
app.ready(function(model) {
    var tiny = derby.use(require('../../lib/app/TinyMCE'))
    //other client-side code
}
```

and put the following into `lib/app/TinyMCE.js`:

```
var derby = require('derby')
module.exports.decorate = 'derby'; //because before I got an 'decorate' is undefined error...
module.exports.TinyMCE = function() {
    //code
}
```

But now I'm getting a `object is not a function` error.

Am I even on the right track? I also considered putting the code in the public directory, but the cache-expiration of one year makes this rather inconvenient.

Also, is there really no `isServer` or `isClient` method to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I don't know whether that's a good way, but I got it working:

```
module.exports = tiny
tiny.decorate = 'derby'
function tiny() {
     //code
}
```